# Ember application runtime error uncaught referenceerror ember is not defined vendor.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to upgrade the ember from 3.* to 4.12.2. I'm not getting any compilation issues but when I run my application I'm getting "**uncaught referenceerror ember is not defined"** inside the vendor.js file.

below is the console log in browser.

```
vendor.js?v=95293905-3319-4db8-8355-c1297659dfa6:98  Uncaught ReferenceError: Ember is not defined
    at a.callback (vendor.js?v=95293905-3319-4db8-8355-c1297659dfa6:98:389464)
    at a.exports (vendor.js?v=95293905-3319-4db8-8355-c1297659dfa6:1:2153)
    at a._reify (vendor.js?v=95293905-3319-4db8-8355-c1297659dfa6:1:2747)
    at a.reify (vendor.js?v=95293905-3319-4db8-8355-c1297659dfa6:1:2532)
    at a.exports (vendor.js?v=95293905-3319-4db8-8355-c1297659dfa6:1:2125)
    at a._reify (vendor.js?v=95293905-3319-4db8-8355-c1297659dfa6:1:2747)
    at a.reify (vendor.js?v=95293905-3319-4db8-8355-c1297659dfa6:1:2532)
    at a.exports (vendor.js?v=95293905-3319-4db8-8355-c1297659dfa6:1:2125)
    at a._reify (vendor.js?v=95293905-3319-4db8-8355-c1297659dfa6:1:2747)
    at a.reify (vendor.js?v=95293905-3319-4db8-8355-c1297659dfa6:1:2532)
```

[image]

Any help appreciated, Thank you in advance.

Regards

I tried removing deprecated libraries, tried using auto import still getting this same issue

Comment: hello! can you provide a stack trace and a snippet of the area in vendorjs with the problem?

Comment: Hi @NullVoxPopuli, Added the browser console log along with the vendorjs snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ember v4 using `Ember` without importing it was removed. This was deprecated in v3.

[image]

Your screenshot of the problem area was most helpful -- it reveals that `ember-islands/utils/reconciler` needs to have `import Ember from` ember` in it. It seems like the [latest version](https://github.com/mitchlloyd/ember-islands/blob/master/addon/utils/reconciler.js#L1) has that import, so hunch is now that something is going wrong with the polyfill included here: https://github.com/mitchlloyd/ember-islands/blob/master/package.json#L23-L24

To unblock your upgrade, I would use [`patch-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) or npm/yarn/pnpm overrides to update the dependencies of the library -- it looks like it's had no maintenance in the last 4-5 years, so if you want to continue using it -- you may need to fork (this has the advantage, where you can also make the addon do whatever you want).

Comment: upgrade ember islands version resolved the issues, thank you.